# Conversion of Foxpro code to Set-Based MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-foxpro, foxpro

Trying to convert a Visual Foxpro code to set-based MySQL query. Following is the code segment from Foxpro

```
lnFound=0
IF LnFound = 0 .and. rcResult = "ALL" AND PcOpOrIp = "OP"
    SELECT PFile
    LcTag  = ORDER()
    SET ORDER TO TAG PtcntlNm
    =SEEK(LcPatientNo)
    SCAN WHILE PtcntlNm = LcPatientNo
        IF GcMResult <= "0"
            GcMResult = "1-7MAT-PTC"
        ENDIF
        IF MONTH(cSRa.Fromdate) = MONTH(pFile.Fromdate) ;
             .AND. pFile.ThruDate >= cSRa.ThruDate
            ** Check From/Thru Date against pFile
            IF (ABS(cSRa.totalchrg) = (pFile.BDeduct+pFile.Deduct+pFile.Coinsur)) .OR. cSRa.Tchrgs = (pFile.BDeduct+pFile.Deduct+pFile.Coinsur) .or. (ABS(cSRa.totalchrg) = pFile.Total .OR. cSRa.Tchrgs = pFile.Total)
                IF lnFound = 0
                    gcRecid = recid
                    gcmResult=rcResult
                ENDIF
                lnFound = lnFound + 1
                gcUNrECID = gcunRecid + IIF(EMPTY(gCUNreCID),Recid,[,]+recid)
            ENDIF
        ENDIF
    ENDSCAN
    SELECT PFile
    SET ORDER TO &LcTag
ENDIF
```

I have a table named pfile which I'am trying to join with another table named csra. The main aim of this is to set the record_id (gcrecid) based on the condition of three nested if statements. After setting the gcrecid variable the lnfound variable is set to one hence the third if statement condition is false from the second iteration onwards.

Here is the MySQL stored procedure which I came up with and as you can see I'm not able to completely convert the code in an efficient manner.

```
UPDATE csra AS cs 
  JOIN p051331s AS p ON cs.patientno = p.ptcntlnm 
SET cs.recid = p.recid
  , cs.mcsult = "ALL"
  , cs.lnfound = '"1"'
WHERE cs.provider = '051331' 
  AND cs.lnfound = "0" 
  AND cs.RECID IS NULL
  AND month(cs.fromdate) = month(p.fromdate) 
  AND p.thrudate >= cs.ThruDate
  AND ABS(cs.totalchrg) = (p.bdeduct+p.deduct+p.coinsur) 
   OR cs.tchrgs = (p.bdeduct+p.deduct+p.coinsur) 
   OR ABS(cs.totalchrg) = p.total OR cs.tchrgs = p.total;
```

Any lead in this regard will be much appreciated as I've been working on this procedure for a couple of day with no noticeable results.

Comment: If I'm reading the original code correctly, it's concatenating data from multiple records into a single string, right? I know how to do that in SQL Server, but not in MySQL. Hoping my comment helps someone who knows how to do in MySQL.

Comment: You are pulling what APPEAR to be VFP variable context as actual column names.  What would really be good is to provide the table structures (of applicable columns used if you need to abbreviate), AND some sample data (even if you have to change internally private values.  If providing data, please use spaces between sample column data for readability.  Just edit your existing question with the new details.  Thanks

Comment: @TamarE.Granor Thank you for the reply. Actually I'm not trying to concatenate strings, the values bdeduct, deduct and coinsur are integers and I'm just adding their values as (p.bdeduct+p.deduct+p.coinsur) in the mysql query above.

Comment: @DRapp I have created a MySQL table corresponding to Foxpro's dbf file and the MySQL query is fetching records from that table.

Comment: @Vizkrig, I understand you created a corresponding table in MySQL, but by seeing the table CONTENT (and column names), and what you EXPECT the results to look like from such sample data will help us with whatever roll-up aggregations you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

According to this partial VFP code (which is not clear on variables it uses) there is no code to be converted to set based at all. Corresponding mySQL or MS SQL or any other SQL series backend code would simply be "nothing". ie: this would be equivalant:

```
-- Hello to mySQL or MS SQL
```

PS: On your trial to convert to an update code, inner joining with csra is wrong. It is not joined in VFP code, csra values are constant --unless there is a relation on fields set-- (pointing to the "current row" values in csra only). You would want to make them into parameters as with the rest of memory variables (which is not clear from the code which ones are memory variables).